# Not a single-group group function while using case when statements

Tags: sql, oracle

In a query I am trying to use case when keywords. I have to check for 3 conditions there. But I am getting   Not a single-group group function error. Any syntax error in my query? Please guide.

Query is

```
SELECT  
        CASE WHEN DIST_TYPE_ID IN (5033,5034,5035,5036) 
        THEN MIN (b2b_start_dt +NVL(access_lead_Days,0))
        ELSE 
             CASE WHEN MAX(overridden) = 0 
             THEN NVL (MIN (src_start_dt), MIN (b2b_start_dt)) 
             ELSE MAX(B2B_START_dT) END 
        END as start_date 

FROM    prog_access_movie_v         

WHERE   trunc(SYSDATE) BETWEEN b2b_start_dt AND b2b_end_dt      
        AND (user_id IS NOT NULL OR GROUP_ID IS NOT NULL)        
        AND dist_type_id IN (5034) AND prog_id = (432899)
```

Comment: Presumably, you are using MySQL.  Oracle would generate an error for your query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I am using Oracle. How to overcome this error?

Comment: . . I don't know.  The error is easy to fix, but I have no idea what you intend for your query to do.  It is often more useful to include sample data and desired results in a question.  A non-working query often doesn't convey much information.

Comment: I'm guessing it's the MAX.  If you had "select src_start_date, MAX(overridden)" the db would complain about wanting a "group by"

Comment: This is because MAX, MIN etc. are Aggregate functions and we need to use a GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I want to fetch a date column. If I remove 1st case, it  is working fine. 1st case is  CASE WHEN DIST_TYPE_ID IN (5033,5034,5035,5036) THEN MIN (b2b_start_dt +NVL(access_lead_Days,0)).

Comment: It looks like you are mixing single and group actions - you have e.g. MAX(B2B_START_dT) but no GROUP BY (e.g. should it be GROUP BY DIST_ID or some such) and you are using DIST_TYPE_ID IN (5033...) but no MAX/MIN. But data examples and expectations would help!

Comment: @Sid . I used group by access_lead_Days. It says not a group by expression.

Comment: @Captain - U r absolutely right..:) I was just trying with group by access_lead_date. Added group_by dist_type_id and got the result. Thank you..:)

Comment: I second @Captain, he's right.  Group by function should only contain Aggregate functions in select clause and the column on which grouping is being done.

Answer (score 2):

This is the `select`:

```
SELECT  (CASE WHEN DIST_TYPE_ID IN (5033, 5034, 5035, 5036) 
              THEN MIN(b2b_start_dt + NVL(access_lead_Days, 0))
              ELSE (CASE WHEN MAX(overridden) = 0 
                         THEN NVL(MIN(src_start_dt), MIN(b2b_start_dt)) 
                         ELSE MAX(B2B_START_dT)
                    END)
         END) as start_date
```

In terms of aggregation, everything is fine except for the condition on `DIST_TYPE_ID`.  If you had:

```
SELECT  (CASE WHEN MAX(DIST_TYPE_ID) IN (5033, 5034, 5035, 5036) 
              THEN MIN(b2b_start_dt + NVL(access_lead_Days, 0))
              ELSE (CASE WHEN MAX(overridden) = 0 
                         THEN NVL(MIN(src_start_dt), MIN(b2b_start_dt)) 
                         ELSE MAX(B2B_START_dT)
                    END)
         END) as start_date
```

Or:

```
SELECT  (CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN DIST_TYPE_ID IN (5033, 5034, 5035, 5036) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
              THEN MIN(b2b_start_dt + NVL(access_lead_Days, 0))
              ELSE (CASE WHEN MAX(overridden) = 0 
                         THEN NVL(MIN(src_start_dt), MIN(b2b_start_dt)) 
                         ELSE MAX(B2B_START_dT)
                    END)
         END) as start_date
```

Or a myriad of other possibilities, then the query should parse and execute.

Answer (score 0):

It was a silly mistake from me . Group by dist_type_id worked out.

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN DIST_TYPE_ID IN (5033,5034,5035,5036) THEN MIN (b2b_start_dt +NVL(access_lead_Days,0))
 ELSE CASE WHEN MAX(overridden) = 0 THEN NVL (MIN (src_start_dt), MIN (b2b_start_dt)) ELSE MAX(B2B_START_dT) END END as start_date

 FROM prog_access_movie_v         
 WHERE trunc(SYSDATE) BETWEEN b2b_start_dt AND b2b_end_dt       
 AND (user_id IS NOT NULL OR GROUP_ID IS NOT NULL)        
 AND dist_type_id IN (5034) AND prog_id = (432899)
 group by access_lead_days, dist_type_id
```